# How can i print specific column value only?

Tags: php, laravel

**Controller:**

```
 $dataAnnouncement = DB::table('announcements')->where('id', 2)->get('message');

    return view('student.index', 
    compact('dataAnnouncement'));
```

**Announcement View:**

```
 <textarea id="announcement" name="announcement" rows="4" cols="50">{{ $dataAnnouncement }}</textarea>
```

**Output:**

[image]

I want to output only the Brandyn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->get()` returns a `Collection` of **multiple** rows from your `announcements` Table, but you're only asking for a single record by doing `->where('id', 2)`.

Instead of `->get()`, use `->first()`:

```php
$dataAnnouncement = DB::table('announcements')
->where('id', 2)
->first();

return view('student.index', ['dataAnnouncement' => $dataAnnouncement]);
```

*Note:`['dataAnnouncement' => $dataAnnouncement]` and `compact('dataAnnouncement')` are equivalent, but the documentation suggests to use this `[]` syntax instead of `compact()`.*

Then, in your view, access the `message` property:

```html
<textarea id="announcement" name="announcement" rows="4" cols="50">{{ $dataAnnouncement->message }}</textarea>
```

Additional Note: This code will fail if you don't have a record with an `id` of 2 in your `announcements` database table. You can use `->firstOrFail()` to automatically trigger an `HTTP 404` error if no record is found, or manually handle a `null` value by doing something like `{{ $dataAnnouncement?->message }}` or `{{ $dataAnnouncement ? $dataAnnouncement->message : '' }}`